# PostgreSQL updating more rows than in where condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following simple SQL update:

```
update t2 set col = 2 
from t2, t1
where t2.id = t1.id
    and t1.name = 'test';
```

But all the rows in t2 are updated! i.e. not just the one with the `id` where `name` is 'test', how do I achieve this in Postgres?

Comment: *"where t1.id = t1.id"* Is that a typo?

Comment: oops, yes thanks fixed, still same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got too much from `from t1,t2`
do this:

```
update t2 set col = 2 
from t1
where t2.id = t1.id
    and t1.name = 'test';
```

If you must have t2 in the from alias it and join all three tables in the where..

```
update t2 as t2_up set col = 2 
from t2 as t2_from , t1
where t2_from.id = t1.id
    and t2_up.id = t2_from.id
    and t1.name = 'test';
```

Comment: Cannot believe I have got so far in life without knowing this! I guess from <table updating> is implied already so not needed again in from like with a select?

Comment: yes, the the table after update is implied.and the the row values are auomatically available in the where clause.

Comment: @markmnl: [From the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html): "*Note that the target table must **not** appear in the from_list, unless you intend a self-join (in which case it must appear with an alias in the from_list).*"

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you really mean:

```
update t2
    set col = 2 
from t2 join
     t1
     on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.name = 'test';
```

The condition `t1.id = t1.id` doesn't really make much sense in a query.  It is equivalent to `t1.id is not null`.  Hence, all rows in `t2` would get updated due to the cross join.